# How to read a file with Unicode contents

Tags: c++, c, api, rdp

How can I read a file with Unicode contents using C/C++?

I used ReadFile function to read a file with Unicode contents, but it doesn't have the true output. **I want to have a buffer that contains all the contents of the file**

I use this code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hndlRead;
    OVERLAPPED ol = {0};

    CHAR* szReadBuffer;
    INT fileSize;

    hndlRead = CreateFileW(L"file", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if (hndlRead != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        fileSize = GetFileSize(hndlRead, NULL);
        szReadBuffer = (CHAR*) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, (fileSize)*2);
        DWORD nb=0;
        int nSize=fileSize;
        if (szReadBuffer != NULL)
        {
            ReadFile(hndlRead, szReadBuffer, nSize, &nb, &ol);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to read this file correctly?

This is nb and szReadBuffer:

[image]

This is my file content in notpad++:

[image]

Comment: Please provide more details (what's an RDP file?) Give us a code sample of what you have tried. Also, read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on SO.

Comment: RDP file is a file like json, sql, txt, ... there is no need to say `what's an RDP file?`

Comment: I mean, what format is it? What does it contain? What is your expected output when reading?

Comment: @joe There is a difference between reading text files and binary files. Also, you use different tools for specific files like xmls, jsons etc. So there is need to say whats and `.RDP` file. And it's  good idea to give answers to questions asked in comments, as they are asked by people who try to solve your problem.

Comment: Also, define 'true output', what are you expecting to get? Do you really need to just 'read' the file, or also 'parse' its content into some kind of structured data?

Comment: I know jsons, xmls, .... but I want some body who know the rdp file

Comment: this is the [rdp file format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg156129(v=winembedded.70).aspx)

Comment: @MichaelWalz I know this, but I can't get the content of the file with readfile

Comment: @joe please show more code. It's hard for us to spot errors in code that we can't see.

Comment: no @MichaelWalz, I can read any file, but the problem is a rdp file..., and the code is the whole code, it's may main() content

Comment: @roalz I want to read it and the parse the content

Comment: @joe please show a [mcve].

Comment: @MichaelWalz Why don't you believe, thats my whole code, I edit my question again and put all the main.cpp content

Comment: With the provided source code, what your debugger is showing to say " doesn't have the true output" ? Are the conditions "`if (hndlRead != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)`" and the "`if (szReadBuffer != NULL)`" equal to "True" ?

Comment: @J.Piquard Yes, they are true and ReadFile returns true too, but szReadBuffer isn't equals to the file content

Comment: @joe, you are using `CHAR* szReadBuffer;` to read a Binary file. Your buffer should be declared as `BYTE* szReadBuffer;` and check the `nb` returned value to verify if all the file has been loaded.

Comment: Why you are allocating twice the size of the buffer `HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, (fileSize)*2);` replace `'*2);'` by `'*sizeof(BYTE));'`.

Comment: @joe I'didn't believe that it was youw whole code, because it wasn't. Now after your edit it is and now we can have a look.

Comment: I add Two Image in my question, please look at them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine. It reads the rdp file verbatim into memory.

You are troubled by the [BOM (byte order mark)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of the rdp file.

If you look at the rdp file with text editor (notepad for instance) you will see this:

```
screen mode id:i:2
use multimon:i:0
desktopwidth:i:2560
desktopheight:i:1600
....
```

If you look at the rdp file with a hexadecimal editor you will see this:

```
0000 FFFE 7300 6300 7200 6500 6500 6E00 2000 ..s.c.r.e.e.n. .
0008 6D00 6F00 6400 6500 2000 6900 6400 3A00 m.o.d.e. .i.d...
....
```

`FFFE` is the byte order mark which indicates that the file is a text file encoded in little endian UNICODE, so each character takes 2 bytes instead of 1 byte.

Once the file read in memory you will get this (0x00318479 being the address `szReadBuffer` points to):

[image]

- BTW 1: you should call `CloseHandle(hndlRead)` once the file has been read.
- BTW 2: you should'nt use `HeapAlloc` but rather `malloc` or `calloc`.

Corrected program:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
  HANDLE hndlRead;

  WCHAR* szReadBuffer;   // WCHAR instead of CHAR
  INT fileSize;

  hndlRead = CreateFileW(L"rdp.RDP", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

  if (hndlRead != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    fileSize = GetFileSize(hndlRead, NULL);
    szReadBuffer = (WCHAR*)calloc(fileSize + sizeof(WCHAR), 1);  // + sizeof(WCHAR) for NUL string terminator
    DWORD nb = 0;
    int nSize = fileSize;
    if (szReadBuffer != NULL)
    {
      ReadFile(hndlRead, szReadBuffer, nSize, &nb, NULL);
    }

    CloseHandle(hndlRead);   // close what we have opened

    WCHAR *textwithoutbom = szReadBuffer + 1;  // skip BOM

    // put breakpoint here and inspect textwithoutbom

    free(szReadBuffer);  // free what we have allocated
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggests @MickaelWalz, the file format of the RDP file is now Unicode.

Here is a way to read and display the content of that file:

> - Use `wchar_t *` buffer instad of `CHAR *` or `BYTE *` buffer.
> - Check if the `ReadFile()` has been successfully performed `bRet == True` and `nSize == nb`.
> - Start to the second WCHAR to exclude the 0xFFFE Unicode identifier.
> - Don't forget to close your file `CloseHandle(hndlRead);` !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hndlRead;
    OVERLAPPED ol = {0};

    //BYTE* szReadBuffer;
    INT fileSize;
    wchar_t *szReadBuffer;

    hndlRead = CreateFileW(L"rdp.RDP", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if (hndlRead != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        fileSize = GetFileSize(hndlRead, NULL);
        szReadBuffer = (wchar_t *) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, (fileSize)*sizeof(wchar_t));
        DWORD nb=0;
        int nSize=fileSize;
        BOOL bRet;
        if (szReadBuffer != NULL)
        {
            bRet = ReadFile(hndlRead, szReadBuffer, nSize, &nb, &ol);
            if ((bRet) && (nb == nSize)) {
                printf("%02X,%02X... %02X\n",szReadBuffer[0],szReadBuffer[1],szReadBuffer[nb-1]);
                std::wcout << L"info " << (szReadBuffer+1) << L" " << nb << std::endl;
            }
        }
        CloseHandle(hndlRead);
    }

    return 0;
}
```